# How does one determine the process causing an ARP request?

Tags: networking, rhel, netstat, arp

I have a machine that runs a network intensive application that spawns many processes. I noticed recently that the machine is producing ARP requests looking for an IP address that does not exist. I would like to trace down which process on the box is causing the ARP requests to be generated for the sake of troubleshooting (so I can know which part of the application is looking for this non-existant IP).

IP's have been changed but they aren't important anyhow.

I discovered these ARP requests by running `tcpdump` on another machine on the same network:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 arp -t -n
ARP, Request who-has 1.1.1.100 tell 1.1.1.1, length 46
```

There isn't meant to be a device with the address `1.1.1.100`, so I want to find what process on `1.1.1.1` is looking for it.

I tried using `ss -np | grep 1.1.1.100` as well as `netstat -np | grep 1.1.1.100` (`netstat` is considered deprecated in place of `ss` for those curious, `ss` has most of the same options and is meant to perform the same functions). Neither of these return any results, likely because `ss` and `netstat` list open sockets, and the ARP request would pre-date a socket being created.

So how can I discern what process causes an ARP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ss` does show you connections that have not yet been resolved by arp. They are in state `SYN-SENT`. The problem is that such a state is only held for a few seconds then the connection fails, so you may not see it.  You could try rapid polling for it with

```
while ! ss -p state syn-sent | grep 1.1.1.100; do sleep .1; done
```

One way to extend the time in this state is to set an arbitrary hard-wired mac address for the IP address in your arp table. Then a connect will take over 30 seconds to timeout, and will be easier to see with `ss`.

For example, with my eth0 at 192.168.1.1

```
$ socat tcp:192.168.1.100:80 - 
$ arp -i eth0 -n | grep 192.168.1.100
192.168.1.100 (incomplete) eth0
```

setting the mac address makes the socat easily visible

```
$ sudo arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.100 80:ef:00:ff:ff:ff
$ socat tcp:192.168.1.100:80 - &
$ ss -p state syn-sent
Netid  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port                
tcp    0      1      192.168.1.1:46608 192.168.1.100:http users:(("socat",pid=20230,fd=3))
```

Comment: If the connection is only held for a few seconds would it also be valid to just run a recurring `ss`? Something like `watch -n 1 "ss -np | grep 1.1.1.100"`? I like the idea of repeated `ss` more than adding a manual `arp` entry, even if only temporary.

Comment: Yes, if you keep a careful eye on the output you should see it pass by. You might be better off doing `while ! ss -p state syn-sent|grep 1.1.1.100;do sleep .1; done`

Comment: You should add that to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#readme) program that displays per-process network traffic.
But arp won't be generated directly by running process it would be generated by OS. Some program may want to communicate with 1.1.1.100 and this IP doesn't exists in ARP table so ARP packet is being sent by OS to populate mac address table.

Is DHCP server running on 1.1.1.1? I would say that DHCP server probes addresses in the lease range to see which of them are free.

Comment: DHCP server is not running on `1.1.1.1`. DHCP should only probe an address in the lease range before assigning it (so if something requested an IP, and the DHCP server was going to assign it `1.1.1.100` it would probe `1.1.1.100` first to see if it was safe to assign).

Comment: So only one options would be dtrace, strace to find which process is trying to communicate.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid `strace` because there are many process trees, but it is the next thing to fall back on. I was hoping to match from ARP -> Process rather than from Process -> ARP. But it may be the only choice.

Comment: another option is to setup dummy host/alias interface on Ethernet card. which is being arped for and check what traffic is being sent to this host, you can use nethogs to identify proccess which is sending traffic. So arp will be replied mac address added to arp table and than packet will be delivered to destination host.

Comment: Oh I like that. I'll be able to give it a shot in a bit. If you add that to your answer and my testing pans out I'll accept.

Comment: ach, no dice on assigning the IP elsewhere, probably because the traffic is expecting a particular response/handshake before establishing a connection. `strace` worked but it wasn't as nice a solution as I would have liked because I had to find all the processes I suspected first, then `strace` them all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem just now.  Having tried a few things, I came back to sysdig.  This worked nicely for me:

```
sysdig fd.rip=1.1.1.100
```

In my case, the IP in question was actually 172.28.210.22, and the output was:

```
# sysdig fd.rip=172.28.210.22
5987580 15:42:55.952661802 7 dhclient (1232) < sendto res=300 data=...............*............RT..................................................
6318682 15:43:01.237021372 7 dhclient (1232) > sendto fd=6(<4u>172.28.210.22:67->172.28.208.42:68) size=300 tuple=0.0.0.0:68->172.28.210.22:67
6318683 15:43:01.237080305 7 dhclient (1232) < sendto res=300 data=...............*............RT..................................................
6926596 15:43:10.092470330 7 dhclient (1232) > sendto fd=6(<4u>172.28.210.22:67->172.28.208.42:68) size=300 tuple=0.0.0.0:68->172.28.210.22:67
6926608 15:43:10.092541255 7 dhclient (1232) < sendto res=300 data=...............*............RT..................................................
8882391 15:43:31.595024934 7 dhclient (1232) > sendto fd=6(<4u>172.28.210.22:67->172.28.208.42:68) size=300 tuple=0.0.0.0:68->172.28.210.22:67
```

which clearly showed that this was coming from dhclient.

Comment: This `sysdig` is a solid find. Their documentation could be better (`The list of available fields can be obtained with 'sysdig -l'.` rather than in the `man` page..) but it seems like a powerful tool, and distributed with Debian and Ubuntu already no less!

Comment: Yeah, sysdig is awesome.  Be sure to take a look at `csysdig` too....